# Error pulling data from firestore to flutter streams

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

i have a collection messages from which i am trying to get data into the stream but it is showing the following error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asdXB.jpg)

this is the code for streams

```
StreamBuilder(
              builder: (context,snapshot){
                if(snapshot.hasData){
                  final messages=snapshot.data;
                List<Text> messageWidgets=[];
                for(var message in messages){
                  final messageText=message.get('text');

                  final  messageSender=message.data()['sender'];
                  final messageWidget=
                      Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
                messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
                }
                return Column(
                  children: messageWidgets,
                );
                }
              },
            stream: _firestore.collection("message").snapshots(),
            ),
```

can someone help me figure this out

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
final messages=snapshot.data;
```

To this:

```
final messages=snapshot.data.docs;
```